# What is the term for the number of wavelengths in a wave packet?

Tags: waves, terminology, wavelength, superposition

If I have several wave packets, such that they consist of 1, 2, 3, etc. wavelengths of a single wave with a set frequency/amplitude what do the wave packets vary by?

Ie. what is the generic term for the number of wavelengths in a wave or wave packet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a common term for that, but it's related to the idea of *fractional bandwidth*. The number of cycles in a packet is $k/(fractional bandwidth)$, with constant $k \approx 1$, depending on exactly how you define bandwidth and count cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, this concept doesn't seem to be in common use, but the most common terms I've found are wave periods or wave cycles.

Ie. a wave three wavelengths "long" has three wave periods or three wave cycles.